# cassandra Tables and Data Model

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, edi

I am trying to create cassandra table with 350-400 columns and probably 4-5 billion records. Question is what care needs to be taken in order to achieve RDBMS style queries. I understand table must be designed as per query requirements. Since it is going to have 350-400 columns, I am sure not matter how I choose the primary key my queries will need too many secondary indexes. If that is not the case then how do I design the Tables. Do I use spark to upload data into multiple sub tables or Do I create Materialised views on that big table? if not what are the other solutions available.

Also if there are 2 or 3 such big files with relation between them how do I manage to setup the tables, so that I can run queries which are using data from both the tables.

Thanks
tom

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store? On how much of those 350-400 columns will you restrict searching? Are all columns filled all the time or sparse?

I don't know your data or data model - but so many columns could indicate that your data model may need improving.

Comment: the reason for using such a long list of columns is because we dont have joins. out of 350-400 we might use about 50-80. and in that 50-80 we might use 10-12 fields for searching. We are storing EDI data.

Comment: You could go an build a small row with your 10-12 search files and put the others as key-value pairs (think of clustering columns) or as json or similar payload.

Comment: Yes. But what if we want those other fields in future. Say all of a sudden client ask for 5 more columns for search purpose them how do we handle? I know I am asking too many doubts but, unfortunately I dont see any documentation regarding these. I have gone through DataStax documentation but they dont answer my questions. thank you very much for answering them.

Comment: DataStax Enterprise comes with DSE Search (Solr integration) which might help, also going with many columns to be searchable might be the wrong thing. Cassandra can be really fast - if your queries can hit a single partion (think of node that stores the data), but can be really slow (and will refuse to work hinting "ALLOW FILTERING" to remind you) otherwise if you need to hit multiple partition. A primary key can be build of a partion key (node) and cluster columns (order of data in a partition).

Comment: I cant find my example right now - but if you like I can make up a new one tomorrow.

Comment: Sure. That will be of great help. Also how do I achieve joins between Table A and Table B, is the best way to use spark or create one more set of table C and pull the data from old tables.